# Summation and count of dictionary items inside of a another dictionary using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In a json file with huge data I got 24 columns with 700k rows, one of columns have a dictionary inside, so i selected that column below:

```
 dataset = pd.read_json('ecommerce-events - Copia.json', lines=True)
 dataset.loc[dataset['eventType']=="transaction"]
```

In transaction column has "price", wanna sum all prices times quantity, how I do this with pandas?

```
 'url': 'da7caa77e2729e12b32a9d7d1a324652ce2264a6',
 'referrer': '6e03ee62984224d0c0f08d4b68b819297d7f4d14',
 'order': 5545,        # unique transaction id
 'orderItems': [{      # list of products bought in that transaction
     'product': 16493, # product id
     'price': 19.9,    # product unit price
     'quantity': 1.0
```

[print](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Js5Va.png)

Comment: That image is not self-explanatory at all. Please post your dataframe *as text*, not as an image.  Also include a desired output

Comment: It seems that you need something like: `df.orderItems.apply (lambda x: x['price'])`

Comment: @Lucas, your formula is perfect but:
"TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"

Comment: It looks like you have some NaN in that column. You should filter them (drop them or complete them with dict with the keys but empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def summation(x):
value=x["price"] * x["qun"]
return value
```

df=pd.DataFrame({"Transaction":[[{"price":23,"qun":2}],[{"price":25,"qun":2}],[{"price":24,"qun":2}]]})
df["summation_value"]=df[["Transaction"]].apply(lambda x : summation(x[0][0]), axis=1)